# How to call a namespaced Vuex action in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am building an app using NUXT js. I am also using the store `module mode` because using classic mode returned some `depreciation issue`.

The PROBLEM is I get `[vuex] unknown mutation type: mobilenav/showmobilenav` error in my console.

so below are my stores

store/index.js

```js
export const state = () => ({
})
 
export const mutations = ({
})
 
export const actions = ({
})
 
export const getters = ({
})
```

store/mobilenav.js

```js
export const state = () => ({
    mobilenav: false
})

export const mutations = () => ({
    showmobilenav(state) {
        state.mobilenav = true;
    },
    hidemobilenav(state) {
        state.mobilenav = false;
    }
})

export const getters = () => ({
    ismobilenavvisible(state) {
        return state.dropdown;
    }
})
```

the VUE file that calls the mutation

```html
<template>
    <div class="bb" @click="showsidenav">
        <img src="~/assets/svg/burgerbar.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        showsidenav() {
            this.$store.commit("mobilenav/showmobilenav");
            console.log("sidenav shown");
        },
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more detailed example on how to write it.

`/store/modules/custom_module.js`

```js
const state = () => ({
  test: 'default test'
})

const mutations = {
  SET_TEST: (state, newName) => {
    state.test = newName
  },
}

const actions = {
  actionSetTest({ commit }, newName) {
    commit('SET_TEST', newName)
  },
}

export const myCustomModule = {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
}
```

`/store/index.js`

```js
import { myCustomModule } from './modules/custom_module'

export default {
  modules: {
    'custom': myCustomModule,
  },
}
```

`/pages/test.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="actionSetTest('updated test')">Test the vuex action</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  methods: {
  ...mapActions('custom', ['actionSetTest']),
}
</script>
```